# Importance of Correlation in panel data

Tags: r, correlation, generalized-linear-model, panel-data

I have a panel dataset of $N=78$ with 4 repeated measures. While building my model using generalized estimation equation, I am getting correlation parameter of 0.05-0.10 with different correlation structures. My question is how much it is important to have the correlation in the panel data?
Subsequently, I am calculating R-square which is equal to 0.15.
Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Since correlation addresses how much one value changes in presence of the other values, a paired structure of the measurement is implied. So you can take the panel's measurements at two different time points to see if they correlate. You might want to test a) if the correlation coefficient differs from zero, and b) if R_squared is more than zero.